# UWP Hide Navigator on a page

Tags: uinavigationbar, uwp-xaml

I'm starting to learn UWP and I've successfully loaded pages and navigated between them using the SHELLPAGE as my MASTER with a NAVIGATIONVIEW in it.  I do however have a case where I need to load a single page, but I need to HIDE the NAVIGATIONVIEW when that one page is loaded.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the NavigationView on other page, you could try to set the OpenPaneLength as 0 and hide its backbutton and PaneToggleButton. When you back, you can reset OpenPaneLength and display the buttons. For example:

```
NavigationViewControl.OpenPaneLength = 0;
NavigationViewControl.IsBackButtonVisible = NavigationViewBackButtonVisible.Collapsed;
NavigationViewControl.IsPaneToggleButtonVisible = false;
```

**Or**, the NavigationView was displayed in the ShellPage's Frame and it contained a Frame that used to display pages. If you want to display a single page and hide NavigationView, you can also display the single page in the Root Frame. For example:

.xaml:

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavigationViewControl" SelectionChanged="NavigationViewControl_SelectionChanged" >
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Normal Page" Tag="NormalPage" />
        <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Hide Navi Page" Tag="SinglePage" />
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
</NavigationView>
```

.cs:

```
private void NavigationViewControl_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var selectedItem = (NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem;
    if ((string)selectedItem.Tag == "SinglePage")
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SinglePage));
    }
    else
    {
        contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(NormalPage));
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/wcj233/HideNavigationApp) is a sample you can refer to it.

Comment: So, i downloaded your example and I found it useful as that's how I had started my project and ended up using the _SHELLPAGE example from MickeySoft.  Incidentally, the NAVIGATIONVIEWAPP would have worked if I did not need to go multiple layers deep.  In the MickeySoft example, they used a page called SHELLPAGE.  There is a FRAME within it where every other page gets loaded using the standard FRAME.NAVIGATE just like above.  The NAVIGATIONVIEW is located in the SHELLPAGE.  Is there a way for me to COLLAPSE the view from MAINPAGE after I've executed FRAME.NAVIGATE(SINGLEPAGE)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the navigationview after calling `Frame.Navigate(typeof(SinglePage));`? However, when you used Frame.Navigate() method, the navigationview has been covered by SinglePage, why do you still want to hide it?

Comment: Because the SINGLEPAGE still shows the NAVIGATIONVIEW. I don't want the NAVIGATIONVIEW to show even though the SINGLE page is modal.  In my app, the MAINPAGE is my landing page.  There is a SHELLPAGE that has the NAVIGATIONVIEW and all other pages is housed in its FRAME.  When the application starts, the MAINPAGE launches and calls/opens my LOGIN page.  I don't know that I can create a NEW FRAME and open LOGIN and then CLOSE the LOGIN when done so MAINPAGE is CURRENT again.  I tried a NEW FRAME and when closing LOGIN, I got an error - OBJECT NOT SET.

Comment: Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?